# Find the Max and Min of a count SQL

Tags: sql, count, max, min

The question is: For each department, list the max and min enrollment across all sections of courses they offered, considering only those sections that had some enrollment - that is, don't worry about those sections that had no students taking that section.

```
Department(dept_name, building, budget)
Section(course_id, sec_id, semester, year, building, room_number, time_slot_id)
student(student_id, name, major, tot_cred)
takes(student_id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits)
```

The query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM course 
  NATURAL JOIN (SELECT count(student_id) AS tot 
  FROM takes NATURAL JOIN section GROUP BY course_id)
```

^^^ Gives the enrollment. Need to find Max and Min

Comment: So, what's the query you've made?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "count of enrollment" and "group by dept_name".  Are you looking for the total number of students in each dpartment's classes?  The total number of seats filled (students per section x number of sections)?  Something else? You'll need to add more details to your question. One obvious thing you can do is to specify the columns you expect in your output, and what each of those columns means if it's not obvious.

Comment: select dept_name,max(enrollment), min(enrollment)
from department, takes 
where (select count(distinct student_id) as enrollment)
group by dept_name

Comment: You don't have a join condition (btw: you should use explicit `JOIN`s) and your where clause is wrong.

Comment: @AmyMiller how does `department` relate to the other tables? Do you have other tables that relate the `department` to the student?

Answer (score 2):

You would use a subquery for this:

```
select min(cnt), max(cnt)
from (select dept_name, count(*) as cnt
      from student s join
           takes t
           on s.student_id = t.student_id join
           course c
           on t.course_id = c.course_id join
           department d
           on c.department_id = d.department_id
      group by dept_name
     ) t
```

To do this, I imagined that you have a table `course` with a department id in it.  Your tables above have no link to the departments.

Your query simply does not make sense.  You should never use "," in the `FROM` clause.  If you want to do a cross join, then explicitly use `CROSS JOIN`.  I would expect your query to have a syntax error in any database, because `enrollment` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you just need to care about the table `takes`.
Here is my way to do this:

```
SELECT MAX(enrollment) MaxEnrollment, MIN(enrollment) MinEnrollment
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(student_id) enrollment 
    FROM takes
    GROUP BY course_id, sec_id, semester, year
    ) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    course_id,
    min(tot_per_course_sec) min_section_enrolment,
    max(tot_per_course_sec) max_section_enrolment
from course
natural join (
    select course_id, sec_id, count(student_id) as tot_per_course_sec
    from takes
    natural join section
    group by course_id, sec_id
    having count(student_id) > 0
    ) sec_grouped
```